Black Python formatter - setting different line length for some files
I'm using Black Python formatter and I'm looking for a way to control line-length settings for some of the files. E.g. I'd like the default line length to be set in pyproject.toml to 120, but for some files, I'd like to set a line length to e.g. 200. I hope there might be a way of achieving this by using some magical comments at the top of the files?
